# Setting the value of a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see in the following code I'm fetching data from the MySQL database, but I got stuck when I wanted to use fetched "location" to set the "position" of a marker on a google map.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sensor=true"></script>
<script>
  $.getJSON('http://www.wawhost.com/appProject/fetchmarker.php?callback=?', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      localStorage.loc = data[i].location;
    }
  });
</script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: 'new google.maps.LatLng(' + localStorage.loc + ')',
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Call `initialize()` after your JSON has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the request when the page has loaded, and call the `initialize` function from the AJAX success callback.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://www.wawhost.com/appProject/fetchmarker.php?callback=?', function(data) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       localStorage.loc = data[i].location;
     }
     initialize();
  });
});
```

Also, this line looks a bit sketchy. `position` is supposed to be a new `google.maps.LatLng`.

```
position: 'new google.maps.LatLng(' + localStorage.loc + ')'.
```

`LatLng` takes an latitude and longitude argument to construct the object. What you've stored from the request is a *string*, with comma seperated lat and long values.

```
// First split the string into lat and long.
var pos = localStorage.loc.split(",");
// Parse the strings into floats.
var lat = parseFloat(pos[0]);
var lng = parseFloat(pos[1]);    
// Create a new marker with the values from the request.  
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

Try it [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/BWfxw/3/)

Comment: It's supposed to look like this -> 
position: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)

Comment: @alesko007 - If you know what it's supposed to look like then why don't you fix it. I made changes and got it working here. See the edits and the fiddle link.

Comment: @alesko007 - Try using the console window to log and set breakpoints. You should have been able to see that the type was wrong.

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript. Thank you for your help. I hope I'll get it right.

Comment: Good luck. Make sure you use the developer tools (breakpoints, logging, call stacks) in your browser, it will save you a lot of headache.